# Docker: display information for each pulled layer

Tags: virtualization, docker

Whenever I pull an image from a registry, Docker pulls not only the image, but also additional layers. 
Is there a way to tell docker to be more verbose about the layers? E.g., if I

```
$ docker pull IMG1
```

and to do so, the Docker client first pulls IMG0, how can I obtain

```
Unable to find image 'IMG1' locally
Pulling repository REPO_WITH_IMG1
IMG1: Pulling dependent layers 
IMG0: [the information which gets overwritten by] ; Download complete
...
```

instead of

```
Unable to find image 'IMG1' locally
Pulling repository REPO_WITH_IMG1
IMG1: Pulling dependent layers 
e9e06b06e14c: [some information here, then comes] Download complete
```

Comment: A layer is not an image.

Comment: @learningtech What kind of information are you expecting to see?